# Captcha mejorado

Tags: javascript, captcha, recaptcha

He terminado mi primer captcha lo dejaré por aquí si alguien novato como yo esta interesado :)

Un problema que he tenido en el captcha es que a la hora de verificar si en la array de imágenes *arraya* tenía 10 imágenes y *imagSeleccionadas* solo ocupa 9, no lograba verificar, entonces he tenido que eliminar una de las imágenes, que indico antes del script.

Gracias de antemano a todos los que respondáis y espero que a alguien le sirva de algo!

Inserto el código HTML:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css"> -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img id ="imatge0" src="imatgescaptcha/gat1.jpg" onclick="Click(this)"></td>     
                <td><img id ="imatge1" src="imatgescaptcha/gat2.jpg" onclick="Click(this)"></td>  
                <td><img id ="imatge2" src="imatgescaptcha/gat3.jpg" onclick="Click(this)"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>       
                <td><img id ="imatge3" src="imatgescaptcha/gat4.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"></td>
                <td><img id ="imatge4" src="imatgescaptcha/gat5.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"></td>    
                <td><img id ="imatge5" src="imatgescaptcha/inc1.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"></td>            
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img id ="imatge6" src="imatgescaptcha/inc2.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"></td>
                <td><img id ="imatge7" src="imatgescaptcha/inc3.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"></td>
                <td><img id ="imatge8" src="imatgescaptcha/inc4.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"></td>
            </tr>          
        </table>
        <div>
                <button id="validar" onclick="Validacio()">Validacio</button>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I este es el codigo del script, si os fijáis en la siguiente array *arraya* le he tenido que quitar una imagen, esa imagen es *inc2.jpg*
Script:

```
<script>
            //Imatges
            let arraya=["gat1.jpg", "gat2.jpg", "gat3.jpg", "gat4.jpg", "gat5.jpg","inc1.jpg", "inc3.jpg", , "inc4.jpg", "inc5.jpg"];
            var imatgescorrectes=["gat1.jpg", "gat2.jpg", "gat3.jpg", "gat4.jpg", "gat5.jpg"];
            var imatgesincorrectes=["inc1.jpg", "inc2.jpg", "inc3.jpg", "inc4.jpg", "inc5.jpg"];  
            //barrejar array
            function barrejar(){
                arraya=arraya.sort(()=> Math.random() -0.5)
            }
            barrejar();

            for(let i = 0; i<=8; i++){
                    document.getElementById("imatge"+i).src="imatgescaptcha/"+arraya[i]
            }


            let imagSeleccionadas=[]
            //funcio click, dona estils
            function Click(imatge){
                //divideix la cadena de numeros y retorna el valor
                let imageName=imatge.src.split("/").pop()
                if(!imagSeleccionadas.includes(imageName))
                imagSeleccionadas.push(imageName)
                console.log(imagSeleccionadas)
                imatge.style.outline="5px solid red";       
            }
            function Validacio(){
                var verificacio;
                console.log(imagSeleccionadas.length)
                if(imagSeleccionadas.length != 5){
                    alert("Error")
                }
                else{
                    for(let i=0; i<= imagSeleccionadas.length-1;i++){
                   
                        if(imatgescorrectes.includes(imagSeleccionadas[i])){
                        verificacio = true;
                        }
                        else{
                            verificacio = false;
                            i= imagSeleccionadas.length-1;
                        }
      
                    }
      
                    console.log(verificacio);
                }
                if(verificacio == false)
                    location.reload();
                else
                    window.location.href = "https://google.es";
            }
            
        </script>
```